# Mysql cannot start - Could not find valid tablespace file for

Tags: linux, mysql, service, innodb

My mysql service is currently unable to start with the error

> InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'wowcher/temp_import'.

I think I know what the issue is. I have a PHP script which imports CSV files into a temporary table before splitting information to the correct relevant tables.

It would then wipe the temporary table at the end of the script, however for some reason it has been giving errors before completing and wiping the table. So Im pretty sure the temp table is huge right now.

How can I wipe it when I cannot start the mysql service? or is it something else that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql data folder look for *.frm and *.ibd files for the temp table. Remove them manually and then start.